# Decoding HTML Content Inside of a Razor Partial View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that makes use of the following partial view to display user entered notes:

```
@model NoteViewModel

<div title="@Model.Content"><span class="accordion-header">@Model.HeaderText</span></div>
<div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveNote", "Note", null, new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "SaveNoteCallback(data, status, xhr)" }, new { id = ("Note" + Model.NoteId + "_form") }))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AuditId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NoteId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NoteTypeId)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, new { @class = "rteditor" })

        <div class="note-buttons">
            <input class="note-button note-submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Note", new { id = Model.NoteId }, new { @class = "note-button note-delete" })
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

The `Content` property of the model will typically contain HTML content such as `<p>Example</p>`. This content is displayed within a CKEditor instance. This works fine when the partial view is being loaded as part of another view during initial page load. The problem I am having is that I also need to be able to return the partial view to an AJAX callback for rendering via JQuery. When I get the result in JQuery, the `Content` is encoded:

```
<div title="&lt;p&gt;Example&lt;/p&gt;"><span class="accordion-header">Added by John Doe on Aug 05, 2014</span></div>
<div>
    <form action="/Note/SaveNote" class="smartaudit" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-success="UpdateNoteCallback(data, status, xhr)" id="Note50_form" method="post">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AuditId must be a number." data-val-required="The AuditId field is required." id="AuditId" name="AuditId" type="hidden" value="327" />
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field NoteId must be a number." data-val-required="The NoteId field is required." id="NoteId" name="NoteId" type="hidden" value="50" />
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field NoteTypeId must be a number." data-val-required="The NoteTypeId field is required." id="NoteTypeId" name="NoteTypeId" type="hidden" value="2" />
        <textarea cols="20" id="Content" name="Content" rows="2">&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Example&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;</textarea>

        <div class="note-buttons">
            <input class="note-button note-submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
            <a class="note-button note-delete" href="/Note/Delete/50">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

As you can see, I first use the `Content` property directly to set the title attribute on the first `div` element--there the content is properly encoded to `&lt;p&gt;Example&lt;/p&gt;`. I also use the `Content` property again within the `TextAreaFor` html helper. In this case the view double encodes the content within the text area to `&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;Example&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;`. This is from the raw result I get back in my javascript callback--it isn't the result of anything I'm doing in the script.

Here is the controller action which returns the partial view in this scenario:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult SaveNote(NoteViewModel viewModel)
{
    Note note;
    if (viewModel.NoteId == 0)
    {
        note = Db.Notes.Create();
        Db.Notes.Add(note);
    }
    else
    {
        note = Db.Notes.Find(viewModel.NoteId);
    }

    Mapper.Map<NoteViewModel, Note>(viewModel, note);

    Db.SaveChanges();

    Mapper.Map<Note, NoteViewModel>(note, viewModel);

    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/NoteView.cshtml", viewModel);
}
```

Edit: Here is my initial attempt for handling the returned partial view:

```
function SaveNoteCallback(data, status, xhr) {
    var notesContainer = $("#accordion-container");
    var html = $(data);
    html.appendTo(notesContainer);
    notesContainer.accordion("refresh");
    var contentArea = $(".rteditor", html)[0];
    CKEDITOR.replace(contentArea, {
        width: '100%',
        resize_enabled: false,
        htmlEncodeOutput: true
    });
    $(".note-button", html).button();
    $(".note-buttons", html).show();
}
```

I'd like to know what the cleanest way of handling this would be. Is it possible to get the partial view to return the HTML content unencoded? Is it best to just decode it from the client callback function (and how would this be done)?

**Edit 2**: After doing some debugging, it really looks to me like the html content is being double encoded by the `TextAreaFor` and/or `TextArea` html helpers when the view is rendered via the controller's `PartialView` method (as opposed to rendering via `Html.Partial` within another view).

Comment: Please post a js code responsible for "an AJAX callback for rendering via JQuery" as well

Comment: Actually, the code should be same either way. Razor always returns HTML encoded strings unless instructed to do otherwise (`Html.Raw`). Most likely, the issue is that somehow through the JavaScript you use for your AJAX, the content is getting double HTML encoded.

Comment: @Andrei Schenider Added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the source of the problem was that my controller was decoding the `Content` property of the model (via automapper) before rendering the partial view. This was necessary to avoid double encoding. However, what I didn't consider was that the `ModelState` dictionary still contained the encoded version of the `Content` property, so that was still being used by the html helper during view rendering.

The solution was to call `ModelState.Clear()` before returning the partial view.